# could anyone explain this line of code sentance = ' '.join(e.lower() for e in sentance.split() if e.lower() not in stopwords)

Tags: python, for-loop

```
sentance = ' '.join(e.lower() for e in sentance.split() if e.lower() not in stopwords)
```

My Result:

```
for e in sentance:
        if e.lower() not in stopwords:
            sentance=' '.join(sentance)
```

Is the above-mentioned line correct?

Comment: Did you try both and compare the results? They don't do the same thing.

Comment: When I run My Result code in jupyter notebook my system is not responding.

Comment: Then you have a different problem which you need to solve first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is could any one expand me the single line of code into normal one

Answer (score 0):

For every word in a string, if the lowercase version of that string is not in the iterable `stopwords`, join it with spaces. i.e. Give me back the same sentence, but all lowercase minus a set of words.

And no, as you have it, it is not correct. You are splitting sentence into letters rather than tokens of words.

Here is a sample of the code, given line by line:

```
sentence = "I eat food."
stopwords = ["eat"]
words = []
for e in sentence.split():
    if e.lower() not in stopwords:
        words.append(e.lower())
sentence = " ".join(words)
print(sentence)
```